# Kafka Topic Lag is keep increasing gradually when Message Size is huge

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I am using the Kafka Streams Processor API to construct a Kafka Streams application to retrieve messages from a Kafka topic. I have two consumer applications with the same Kafka Streams configuration. The difference is only in the message size. The 1st one has messages with 2000 characters (3KB) while 2nd one has messages with 34000 characters (60KB).

Now in my second consumer application I am getting too much lag which increases gradually with the traffic while my first application is able to process the messages at the same time without any lag.

My Stream configuration parameters are as below,

```
application.id=Application1
default.key.serde=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
default.value.serde=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
num.stream.threads=1
commit.interval.ms=10
topology.optimization=all
```

Thanks

Comment: what number of partitions do you have for topic? and how many instances are running with `application.id=Application1`?

Comment: I have single partition in the topic and two instances of the Application.

Comment: you will not be able to parallel processing of messages with single partition. you need to increase number of partitions (e.g. to 8 partitions, or you could gradually increasing number, and monitor Kafka lag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to consume messages faster, you need to increase the number of partitions (if it's not yet done, depending on the current value), and do one of the following two options:

1) increase the value for the config `num.stream.threads` within your application

or

2) start several applications with the same consumer group (the same `application.id`).

as for me, increasing `num.stream.threads` is preferable (until you reach the number of CPUs of the machine your app runs on). Try gradually increasing this value, e.g go from 4 over 6 to 8, and monitor the consumer lag of your application.

By increasing `num.stream.threads` your app will be able to consume messages in parallel, assuming you have enough partitions.

Comment: Thanks Vasiliy Sarzhynskyi for the answer. I can try this, but I wants to run my application in active passive scenario, so if I will create multiple Partition's into the topic and if there are two or more instance of application are running then my any partition can get assigned to any application instance. Which will break my deployment architecture. So can we change any other config parameter rather than num.stream.threads ?

Comment: AFAIK for active passive you need to have two separate Kafka clusters, and for sure it's allowed to have multiple partitions with such type of architecture (otherwise it was critical limitations for Kafka Streams, but it's not). if you have any specific question regarding Kafka Streams approach for active passive, please ask a separate question on SO